# Linux iproute2 4.3.0 commands for MPLS

Tags: command

I have compiled a new 4.9 kernel with built in MPLS support but am unable to find the relevant commands for its configuration for routing between linux nodes.

My current iproute2 version is listed as 4.3.0-1ubuntu3), I am wondering if I need a specialized iproute2 version installed for MPLS functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I am not terribly familiar with MPLS, but [this](https://pieknywidok.blogspot.com.es/2015/12/mpls-testbed-on-ubuntu-linux-with.html) might be able to answer your question. I don't think you need a specialized iproute, but my knowledge ends at showing MPLS routes:

```
ip -f mpls route show
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found the following commands: ip route add 10.10.10.10/32 encap mpls 100 via inet 192.168.1.2 and ip -f mpls route add 100 as 200 via inet 192.168.2.2, however I get the error "either to is duplicate or encap is garbage" when attempting to use them in a test setup.